# Twilio nodejs client specify PageSize query parameter

Tags: node.js, rest, twilio, api-key, twilio-api

Per the doc, one should be able to specify the PageSize parameter when doing a GET list of resources

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-filters

How do you do this using NodeJS client? The only available parameters to be passed in to /Accounts/[AccountSid]/Messages/[MessageSid] are (from/to/dateSent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the page size like this:

```
client.messages.each(
    {
        pageSize: 10
    }, 
    (message) => console.log(message.body)
);
```

This will make multiple requests to get all the messages, and for each request will return 10 records.

You can also add the `limit` option to limit the total number of records returned, as well as the other filter parameters you mentioned.

```
const accountSid = 'ACc0966dd96e4d55d26ae72df4d6dc3494';
const authToken = "your_auth_token";
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages.each(
    {
        to: '+13335557777', 
        limit: 30, 
        pageSize: 10 
    }, 
    (message) => console.log(message.body)
);
```

The default values are "no limit" (will get all) for `limit` and 50 for `pageSize`.

Comment: How do we assign the pageNumber for retrieval of records?

Comment: How can you achieve pagination "that happens under the hood"? Or manual pagination with the page method using twilio-node? @alexbaban.